# Why C++ would not print the memory address of a char but will print int or bool?

Tags: c++, char, memory-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is address of char data not displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed)

Here is the code and the output:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    bool a;
    bool b;

    cout<<"Address of a:"<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of b:"<<&b<<endl;

    int c;
    int d;

    cout<<"Address of c:"<<&c<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of d:"<<&d<<endl;

    char e;    
    cout<<"Address of e:"<<&e<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

Address of a:0x28ac67

Address of b:0x28ac66

Address of c:0x28ac60

Address of d:0x28ac5c

Address of e:

My question is:
Where is the memory address of the char? And why is it not printed?

Thank you.

Comment: Curious, what compiler are you using?

Comment: You're getting messed up by c++ being too smart by half. Plain ole c `printf` doesn't have this problem because it doesn't attempt to deduce the correct formatting from the type of the argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect that the overloaded-to-`char *` version of `ostream::operator<<` expects a NUL-terminated C string - and you're passing it only the address of one character, so what you have here is undefined behavior. You should cast the address to a `void *` to make it print what you expect:

```
cout<<"Address of e:"<< static_cast<void *>(&e) <<endl;
```

Comment: What does ( void * ) do, can you please give a source ( a link or a search keyword ) for studying?

Comment: @KorayTugay it's a typecast, please use Google. (Just curious: you know what `static_cast<void *>` does, but not what `(void *)` means?)

Comment: No, I did not know that either. Yours just looked a bit easier so I decided to ask you.

Comment: So you are casting the address of e to a pointer? But why void? I will do some search and hopefully understand.

Comment: @KorayTugay Oh, I understand :) I have the exact opposite logic.

Comment: @KorayTugay because `void *` is a general pointer type.

Comment: Thanks. So it is like saying "Pointer of type ANYTHING" ? Thanks. Clear.

Comment: @KorayTugay Pretty much. Rather in C than in C++ (because C++ is more strictly typed, but in C, `void *` can point to any *data* pointer type - not to functions, though.)

Comment: @Yakk can you please explain why I should prefer `static_cast` over C-style casts?

Comment: static_cast shows up in text searches, which mattered a lot more pre-[clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), also and more importantly C casts are nearly unrestricted conversions and thus very error-prone.

Comment: @jthill Thanks. Didn't know that they were considered dangerous. (Well, I did... I always suggest not casting the return value of `malloc()`...)

Comment: 1) C style casts are hard to find in code.  2) C-style casts can easily ramp up from a simple operation (like converting a double to an int) to a dangerous one (like converting a `foo*` to an int).  3) Almost everything a C-style cast can do can be done with the appropriate C++-style cast.  4) If you really are reinterpreting  memory (or whatever operation you want to do with a cast), using `foo* blah;reinterpret_cast<int>(blah)` expresses what you are intending to do better than `foo* blah;(int)blah`.

Answer (score 16):

Strings in C/C++ can be represented by `char*`, the same type as `&e`. So the compiler thinks you're trying to print a string. If you want to print the address, you could cast to `void*`.

```
std::cout << static_cast<void *>(&e) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this previously asked question: [Why is address of char data not displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed)

Also, if you utilize `printf("Address of e: %p \n", &e);` that will work as well.