# ~ Save address of char into variable? ~

Tags: memory

```
char characterA = 'a';     
cout<<"Address of characterA: "<< static_cast<void *>(&characterA) <<endl;
```

Will display Memory Location on screen. How do I save that memory location into double or int variable ?

```
int memory_location = static_cast<void *>(&characterA) // <~~~ no work
```

~ thanks

Comment: By the way, he is referencing [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535254/why-c-would-not-print-the-memory-address-of-a-char-but-will-print-int-or-bool), FYI.

Comment: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: My I ask why you want to store the pointer address into an `int`?  There is no guarantee that the pointer will fit into the `int`, depending on the architecture you are using.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492798/using-intptr-t-instead-of-void).