# Using & operator with char data type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, addressof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is address of char data not displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed)

I was experimenting with ampersand operator and got stuck at this program :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char i='a';
    cout<<&i;
    return 1;
}
```

I was expecting the *address of variable i* as the output but instead the output came as the *value of variable i* itself.

Can anybody explain what just happened? Thanx in advance.

Comment: The above program gives the expected output for int, float, double and long data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `cout::operator<<` has an overload for `const char*`. You'll need an explicit cast to print the address:

```
cout<<static_cast<void*>(&i);
```

This will call the overload with `void*` as parameter, which is the one used to print addresses.

Also note that your code runs into undefined behavior. You only have a single char there, and the overload expects a null-terminated C-string.

Comment: I disagree about that the behavior is undefined. The shift operator behaves exactly as it is documented, it's the data that is corrupted :)

Comment: @DimaRudnik there's no shift operator.

Comment: Isn't that what the operator is called, shift left?

Comment: @DimaRudnik it's not shifting bits, is it? I call it the stream operator, but come to think of it, I'm not sure that's the name.

Comment: @DimaRudnik you're right, it's called the left shift operator. My bad :). The behavior is undefined because `cout` will continue printing until it finds a `'\0'`, but you only own the first `char`. Reading the next ones is illegal.

Comment: For streams it's typically called the stream insertion operator; it has zilch to do with bit shifting. The behavior is undefined the instance that `std::ostream::operator<<(const char *)` attempts to access the character after `a` in `&i` (and this attempted access is exactly what will happen).