# Passing address of a char* C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

```
void Display(char* word)
{
  static char* pointerToWord = word;
  cout << pointerToWord;
}
void initialise(char* word)
{
  Display(word);
}
void main()
{
  char* word[3];
  char* currentWord;

  word[0] = "Hello";
  word[1] = "World";
  word[2] = "hahahaha";

  currentWord = word[0];
  initialise(currentWord);
  
  currentWord = word[1];
  //Displays word[0]
  Display(0);
  currentWord = word[2];
  //Still Displays word[0]
  Display(0);
}
```

Char* were always a bit of a pain in the neck. Can you help me get syntax right?

All I want is

- `initialise()` `Display()`'s pointer to a current word
- use `Display()` to display wherever the pointer is pointing to

  In reality I've got a few classes involved, but this example pretty much illustrates the problem.
  Also I have no intention of modifying the string, so the strings are constant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Are you wanting to call `Display()` to output the currently-pointed-at-word?

Comment: Yes, correct. I fixed the sample a bit

Comment: I just want to pass the address of  currentWord pointer to static char* pointerToWord at Display()

Comment: @MilesOrton I have understood nothing.

Comment: "so the strings are constant"... so where is `const`?

Comment: Assigning a static value from a function argument always reassigns the value.  It's distinct from static initialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is address of char data not displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed)

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as follows: first put `pointerToWord` at global scope:

```
static char* pointerToWord = "";
```

overload Display function:

```
void Display()
{
    cout << pointerToWord;
}

void Display(char* word)
{
    pointerToWord = word;
    Display();
}
```

Comment: Global scope wont work. Thats why I added passOnce() because the pointer to a currentWord is passed by few functions.

Comment: @MilesOrton you'll need to adapt the answer to your 'greater context' since I don't know your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like the following

```
void Display( const char* word = nullptr )
{
  static const char* pointerToWord;

  if ( word != nullptr )  pointerToWord = word;

  if ( pointerToWord != nullptr ) std::cout << pointerToWord;
}
```

Take into account that the function behaviour will be undefined if the object pointed to by pointerToWord is not alive.

Otherwise you should store a copy of the object in the function.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

void Display( const char *word = nullptr )
{
    static std::unique_ptr<char[]> pointerToWord;


    if ( word != nullptr )
    {        
        pointerToWord.reset( std::strcpy( new char[std::strlen( word ) + 1], word ) );
    }        

    if ( pointerToWord != nullptr ) std::cout << pointerToWord.get() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char *word[2] = { "Hello", "World" };

    Display( word[0] );
    Display();

    Display( word[1] );
    Display();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
Hello
World
World
```

Take into account that function main in C++ shall have return type `int` and string literals have types of **constant** character arrays.