# char * point to element not the address

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
void reverse(char * str){
    char * end = str;
    cout << "str" << str << endl;//ABCDE
    cout << "end" << end << endl;//ABCDE
    char tmp;
    if(str){
        while(*end){++end; cout << end << endl;}//ABCDE-->BCDE-->CDE-->DE-->E--> NULL
        --end;//end=E
        cout <<"--end" << end << endl;
        while(str<end){// do swap
            tmp = *str;//*str = str[0] 
            *str++ = *end;//*end = last ele in str[]
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

My input is

```
char test[] = "ABCDE";
cout << test << endl; //ABCDE
reverse(test);
cout << test << endl; //EDCBA
```

I am feeling not good about the pointer, since c++ primer book says char* pointer to the first element of an array, but when I output the pointer end, it is the content of an array not the address.

Also, reverse(test), I mean to give the address of the first element in an array to the pointer, but it turns out give the whole elements to the pointer.

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Don't you have the issue described here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099466/exc-bad-excess-when-trying-to-reverse-a-c-style-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed/4860812#4860812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char*` variable is a pointer to a `char`. A `char[]` is an array of char. Now, an array of `char` can be accessed through a pointer, and for `char*` it is commonly used for string processing (it's used although for other types, but for `char` it's much more common).

```
char test[6] = "ABCDE";
char *start = &test[0]; // will point on A
```

Accessing the array with the pointer can be done with pointer arithmetic:

```
char *end = start + 5; // equivalent to char *end = &test[5]
```

Now when you do:

```
cout << test;
```

or

```
cout << start;
```

It's actually calling an overload of `operator<<` that takes a `const char*`. What this operator does is that it print char starting from the pointer passed until it reaches a null char ('\0').

If you want to print the address contained in the pointer and not the string, you have to cast it to `void*`:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(start);
```

Comment: Error 2 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion) E:\MyProjects\equilibrium index\string_size.cpp 139
This is the error occurs when I try to cout << &test[0], why?

Comment: Your error is strange, don't you have another definition for `test` ? Or is there something else after this on your line (more than just `cout << &test[0];`) ?

Comment: char test[] = "ABCDEF";
 cout << "-- The input add is: --" << (void*)test << endl;
 cout << "the add of first ele is: " << &test[0] << end;

 reverse(test);
 cout << "-- The final result is: --" << test << endl;

Comment: end instead of endl is probably your issue

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is [overloaded to print strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `char*` .

Try:

```
char *test = "ABCDE";
std::cout << (void *) test << std::endl;
```

Comment: it works, but my question is that char array need to add the void* but when working on the int arrays, I just need to simply cout << test <<endl;

Comment: So what do you mean by overloaded for char *?? I mean to operate on the address of elements in an array, we need to know the address right? The char array is somehow different from integer array.

Comment: `operator<<` has a special definition when the argument is of type `char *` that definition is to print the string instead of the address... See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for all overloads, and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for string overloads