# Getting memory address of char returns strange result

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I have this code, that gets the memory address of the integer `myAge` and then prints it out:

```
int myAge = 13;
cout << "myAge is stored at: " << &myAge << endl;
```

The result of that is a normal memory address, as expected. However when I try to apply the same method to a variable with type `char`, it gives a strange result:

```
char myGrade = 'A';
cout << "myGrade is stored at: " << &myGrade << endl;
```

Output:

```
A╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Cast to `void*`, `char*` has a specialization. Looking up the duplicate ...

Comment: After some testing, this seems to work also: `cout << "myGrade is stored at: " << (int *)&myGrade << endl;`

Comment: @odixon But that doesn't make any sense. Just use `void*` for an arbitrary pointer.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed