# integer arrays and character arrays with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would really like some help regarding pointers in c++. Take a look at the following code:

```
int array[3]={4,7,2};
int * a;

a = array;

char Carray[3]={'p','k','\0'};
char * c;

c = Carray;

cout << a << "\n";
cout << c << "\n";
```

Printing a gives back the address of the first element of the array i.e 4 as expected.

But printing c should have given the address of the first element of Carray i.e p but instead it gives the whole string i.e 'pk' in this case. and we havent used a value operator * here.

It will be very kind if someone can explain this to me

Comment: It's printing `c` as a null-terminated string, not it's address.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed

Answer (score 0):

It is because `std::cout` treats `char*` as C-style string. If you need the address you can try:

```
std::cout << (void *) c;
```

Answer (score -1):

you should specify how your variables should be treated during the printout. it's not quite obvious when using streams, so I'd recommend to start from the simple things, namely `printf` :

```
printf( "%d\n", *a );
printf( "%d\n", a );
printf( "%c\n", *c );
printf( "%s\n", c );
```

And see what kind of the output you  get.