# How to display address of a constant character pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

As it can be done for integers and numerical data 
when a pointer is created and displayed like this

```
int number = 5;
int *numberaddress = &number;
cout << "The number is "<< *numberaddress << endl;
cout << "The address of number is "<< numberaddress << endl;
```

However when the same is done for string or constant string pointer it gives the string itself as below

```
char string[20] = "string";
char *stringaddress = string;
const char *stringcopy = "string";
cout << "The string is " << stringaddress << endl;
cout << "The address of string is " << *stringaddress << endl;
cout << "The stringcopy is " << stringcopy << endl;
```

How can I get the address of string by pointers and not just string, is there a way or there is a different method for it ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe. Basically it's `std::cout << (void*)stringaddress`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is address of char data not displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed)

Comment: what is void* doing here ... ?  
i am new to C++, kindly ..

Answer (score 0):

The output operator `<<` treats all pointers to `char` as a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string.

To print the address itself you need to cast it to `void*`:

```
cout << "The address of string is " << static_cast<void*>(stringaddress) << '\n';
```

Note that `*stringaddress` is exactly equal to `stringaddress[0]`, which is the first character in the string.

Comment: @NumaanJaved `static_cast<void*>(stringaddress)` converts the type of `stringaddress` from `char*` to `void*`. The type `void*` is a generic pointer, it can point to anything. And more importantly, it will not be seen as a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string.