# Meaning of ampersand before string name and subscript operator

Tags: c++, string

Recently I've been playing with c++ and noticed that this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string word = "hello there";
    std::cout << &word[2] << '\n';
}
```

prints suffix of variable **word** that is: "llo there".

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it return address of the third character?
I also noticed that this line gives the same result:

```
std::cout << &*(word.begin()+2) << '\n';
```

Could someone explain it to me? Thank in advance

Comment: `std::cout << static_cast<void const*>(&*(word.begin()+2)) << '\n';`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is address of char data not displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860788/why-is-address-of-char-data-not-displayed)

Comment: Thank you @TruthSeeker Exactly what I was just looking for.

Comment: @TruthSeeker yes, thank you. That explains everything